# Swift - Convert URLRequest to cURL

Tags: swift, curl, nsurlrequest, urlrequest

How to convert URL Request to cURL? 
I know there are plugins available in Alamofire / Moya.

But I'm using native code.

Here is how I'm generating `URLRequest`.

```
var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url) // URL is a param herel
var newHeaders: [String: String]
if let cookies = HTTPCookieStorage.shared.cookies {
  newHeaders = HTTPCookie.requestHeaderFields(with: cookies)
} else {
  newHeaders = [: ]
}
newHeaders = // add few more headers here
urlRequest.allHTTPHeaderFields = newHeaders
urlRequest.httpBody = data // set request body
```

How to log a cURL of above request?

Comment: There is no built it option. So you need to do it yourself. What about https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire/blob/master/Source/Request.swift#L876 ? It's quite straightforward. " I know there are plugins available in Alamofire / Moya; But I'm using native code." What's blocking you from getting inspired with their code, how they do it, etc.?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can simply try this
[URLRequest to cURL](https://gist.github.com/abhi21git/3dc611aab9e1cf5e5343ba4b58573596)

To use it in your code first import that extension and then simply call `urlRequest.cURL()` or `urlRequest.cURL(pretty: true)` to print pretty formatted curl.

EDIT: Now the above gist has Alamofire support also

Answer (score 0):

Cleaned up the code and updated it to modern Swift 5.9. Also added the ability to embed any binary data, even those that cannot be decoded into String https://gist.github.com/Rukh/6a0655842e1db5fe48fcd699221d7b68

```swift
import struct Foundation.URLRequest

public extension URLRequest {
    
    func cURL() -> String {
        let cURL = "curl -f"
        let method = "-X \(self.httpMethod ?? "GET")"
        let url = url.flatMap { "--url '\($0.absoluteString)'" }
        
        let header = self.allHTTPHeaderFields?
            .map { "-H '\($0): \($1)'" }
            .joined(separator: " ")
        
        let data: String?
        if let httpBody, !httpBody.isEmpty {
            if let bodyString = String(data: httpBody, encoding: .utf8) { // json and plain text
                let escaped = bodyString
                    .replacingOccurrences(of: "'", with: "'\\''")
                data = "--data '\(escaped)'"
            } else { // Binary data
                let hexString = httpBody
                    .map { String(format: "%02X", $0) }
                    .joined()
                data = #"--data "$(echo '\#(hexString)' | xxd -p -r)""#
            }
        } else {
            data = nil
        }
        
        return [cURL, method, url, header, data]
            .compactMap { $0 }
            .joined(separator: " ")
    }
    
}
```